# Google Maps-based desktop application

Tags: javascript, google, map, multithreading

I want to build a desktop application which has google maps embedded to it. This app should have a thread to read coordinate data online a usb microphone to use. This application will move the google map markers to their new locations based on the data retrieved from online connections on each refresh.

As far as I know gmaps has a javascript API so the first idea in my mind was to embed this mapview into a java applet. So the application will run on a browser. I'm not sure if this will work.

Do you guys have any idea about this or any other advices you might have?

Comment: What's actually the use of the microphone?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>As far as I know, usage of Google Maps for desktop apps is forbidden.</strike>

*<sup>(Scratch that, [it's now OK, so long as it's a publicly available and downloadable app](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_nonweb) - will rewrite this answer.)</sup>*

If you want this to run within a native desktop application - and not in a normal brower connecting to a web-app, though that could also be one way of doing it - you'll need to integrate an in-app browser component.

If you are planning on building this into a Java program, have a look at JDIC and or at integrating a rendering engine (like WebKit).

You can also look at:

- [WebKit in a Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331335/webkit-in-java-application)
- [Rendering Web Pages with WebKit in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850338/rendering-webpages-with-webkit-in-java)

Your question does confuse me a bit though, as you mention using an applet (so, a Java application embedded in a WebPage, to display a map that could directly be displayed in a webpage? "Why, god why?", would be my first reaction). You could use an Applet though, and communicate with it via Javascript, if you want to display the map in the page and do other things in your applet, but that sounds a bit clunky.

Otherwise, as mentioned earlier, you could simply implement your project as a web-app and give access to it from any any platform with a browser supporting JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have references to support this claim?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: Fixed it, that's not the case any more. Sorry.

Comment: @haylem "so, a Java application embedded in a WebPage, to display a map that could directly be displayed in a webpage? "Why, god why?", would be my first reaction" I want to have an applet because as far as I know ordinary html or php web pages do not have a thread to listen a microphone through usb support? and can they listen to a specific ip for data retrieval? Or do they? If im wrong this will be great and ease my job a lot:)

Comment: @dramaticlook: ok, so that's what was confusing. From your title, we think you want to write a desktop app. Now it sounds like you want to write a web-app. See, that's why we need more context in the question. No, you can't do (all of) that with PHP or HTML only. (more coming)

Comment: @dramaticlook: You could indeed do it with an Applet, but that doesn't tie the Google Maps embedding into the page to the applet. An applet can communicate with its container, though to a limited extent. You won't be able to listen to your microphone, but you could listen to a IP for retrieval (or rather do the inverse: query the IP). If we have the bigger picture, we could give a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had the chance to take a look at [GreatMaps](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/)?

It's a .NET control that can be used/embedded in .NET apps. It's compatible with all framework versions and supports many map providers and Google Maps is between them.

Comment: wow this one seems nice. thank you. however I will prefer to go with java which im used to working with :) i found some workarounds like invoking javascript from applet or simulating a thread with javascript. if they do not work i will gove this a try. THANKS ANYWAYS!!!:)